# Invalid date when the date from rest API is retrieved

Tags: ionic-framework

I have retrieved the date from Rest API. The outcome becomes invalid date. Below is my code.  Could you please help me if there is wrong format?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.reportList$ = [];
    from(this.mcsService.getReportList().then(res => {
      for (let item of res.data.items as ReportSummaryItem[]) {
        let itemDate = new Date(item.createdOn);
        item.createdOn = itemDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB') + ' ' + itemDate.toLocaleTimeString();
        console.log("Report Created Date"+item.createdOn);
        this.reportList$.push(item);
      }
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      return res.data.items;
    }));
  }
```

Here is function from Rest API where the date is retrieved.

```
function getRows(req, res) {
    var parameter = { 'createdBy': req.user.username };
    var limitParam = '';
    var offsetParam = '';

    if (typeof req.query.offset === 'undefined') {
        offsetParam = ' OFFSET 0 ';
    } else {
        offsetParam = ' OFFSET ' + req.query.offset;
    }

    if (typeof req.query.limit === 'undefined') {
        limitParam = ' ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY ';
    } else {
        limitParam = ' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' + req.query.limit + ' ROWS ONLY ';
    }


    req.oracleMobile.database.sql(
        'SELECT tr."id", tr."observation", '
        + 'TO_CHAR(tr."createdOn" AT TIME ZONE \'+00:00\', \'dd-MON-yy\') as "createdOn" '
        + 'FROM "' + req.tarTable + '" tr ' +
        ' WHERE tr."createdBy" = :createdBy ' +
        ' ORDER BY tr."createdOn" desc ' + offsetParam + limitParam, parameter
    ).then(
        function (result) {
            res.status(result.statusCode).send(result.result);
        }, function (err) {
            res.status(err.statusCode).send(errorHandler.restErrorHandler(err));
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you check what's returned from you API? Add a console.log(item.createdOn) before the new Date(item.createdOn).

Comment: @Cyril Hanquez , when I use Max accelerator, the date returns as date and time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the format of the date returned is not compatible. It's better to format it following ISO 8601 (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff).

Change your SQL to:

```
+ 'TO_CHAR(tr."createdOn" AT TIME ZONE \'+00:00:00\', \'yyyy-MON-dd\') as "createdOn" '
```

... or something like that (not sure about the syntax as I'm not using oracleMobile database.

Comment: So I should try to change date format in Rest API ? Thank you

Comment: When I remove the following 2 lines and output directly, the date appears. But I still don't know how to get time yet. 
`
`//let itemDate = new Date(item.createdOn);
 `//     item.createdOn = itemDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB') + ' ' + itemDate.toLocaleTimeString();
 `//  console.log("Report Created Date"+item.createdOn);
`